# Checking if specific column contain active cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just started my adventure with apps-script and im already stuck.

I'm trying to write script that triggers when any cell in my table is edited , check if that cell is in specific range ( entire column "O"), then gets cell row and sends mail to person bounded with that row.

As long as I got first and last part, I'm having trouble with checking if that range contains cell :

```
var cell = get.ActiveCell();
var range = ss.getRange("O:O");
```

However there are few similar columns with similar values, and i want to check this one only so far i got something like that

```
var ss = getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("zamówienia");
var cell = get.ActiveCell();
var range =ss.getRange("O:O");

while (i != range.lenght){
    if (cell != range[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    else {
        break;
        return 1;         
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable `range` is an object of class `Range` - what are you expecting to do with `range.lenght` ? For starters, I don't think `lenght` is a valid property of any Apps Script classes, much less any Javascript classes. Review the API reference for supported methods. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) simple trigger, and then you can use the associated [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

Example:

```
// This will show a pop up in your spreadsheet whenever you edit a cell in Column O of any sheet
function onEdit(e) {
  var columnO = 15;
  if (e.range.getColumn() === columnO) {
    Browser.msgBox("Column O");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it like that if anybody's trying to sort out same problem. Added on edit simple trigger

```
function sprawdzenie(){ 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
var  activeCol = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();

if (activeCol === 13){
    var klient = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("c"+activeRow).getValue();
var data_wys = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H"+activeRow).getValue();
var numer_oferty =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E"+activeRow).getValue();
var kolor =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B"+activeRow).getValue();
var prowadzacy = (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AL'+activeRow).getValue() );
var zejscie = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("M"+activeRow).getValue();
var temat = ('Zejście z produkcji ' + numer_oferty + ' wysłanej dnia ' + data_wys);
var wiadomosc = (' Oferta o numerze :' + numer_oferty + ' ' + klient + ' w kolorze : ' + kolor + ' zeszła z dniem : ' + zejscie);

MailApp.sendEmail(prowadzacy, temat, wiadomosc);}
```